# How to convert date format to UTC specific format - yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF+000?

Tags: sql, json, simpledateformat, date-format

I am trying to convert a date time to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF+000. But not sure of the exact format to be used in the query to get the expected value.

The closest I could get is:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(cast(SYSDATE as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF') FROM DUAL
```

I need to validate this against a JSON object which returns the value with +000 at the end.

Comment: It depends on your setup, but in most cases I wouldn’t necessarily do the formatting in the query. It may even be better to parse the string from your JSON into a date-time value and compare with the value retrieved from your database. PS Are you using Oracle?

Comment: The `+000` in JSON, is that a UTC offset, or what is it? Offsets usually come in format `+00:00` or `+0000`, occasionally `+00`, but three digits looks unusual.

Comment: And when you tagged your question simpledateformat, know that the `SimpleDateFormat` class in Java is notoriously troublesome and long outdated, you don’t want to use it. If you have a need for datetime formatting or parsing in Java, use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).